# Email Liquid Templates - Split string and show string[index] inline

Tags: email, shopify, html-email, liquid, liquid-template

I am currently working with liquid templates and I have a string that has a pipe delimiter |. How would I be able to split this string and display the specific string one I want?

I figured out how to split the string:

```
{{ "Cookies | Biscuits" | split: "|" }}
```

But I am unsure where to add the index of the string I need. For example, how can I get "Biscuits"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ "Cookies | Biscuits" | split: "|" | first | strip }}` for **Cookies**

`{{ "Cookies | Biscuits" | split: "|" | last | strip }}` for **Biscuits**

or access it by index:

`{%- assign typeParts = "Cookies | Biscuits" | split: "|" -%}`

and then:
`{{ typeParts[0] | strip }}` for Cookies
`{{ typeParts[1] | strip }}` for Biscuits

Comment: The first part of your answer using "first" & "last" was actually a better solution then what my implementation was going to be. Thank you very much.